# Question about c# and string outside the class or function vs string inside a class or function

Tags: c#

I know that string is a reference type, but I'm having problem understanding why string outside the "refTest" class or function won't behave like the one inside the class "refTest". I mean if I have 2 string named "name" and "name2", and both have the same value since name2 has a copy of name, it will output the same value "A", but then I change the second string value to "B" and this time name and name2 have different value "A" and "B", and then when I do the same thing with a string that is from a class "refTest" it will output name1 and name2 the same value. Aren't both string reference type? Which means they have a pointer on a heap. Right?
I'm getting confused on why string outside the class "refTest" will output a different outcome compared to the one inside the "refTest" class.

Or it is that everytime I declare a string outside the "refTest" class, it will be stored on a different address (heap address)?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        string name = "A";
        string name2 = name;
        Console.WriteLine(name2 + " " + name);
        // >> A A
        name2 = "B";
        Console.WriteLine(name2 + " " + name);
        // >> A B


        refTest test = new refTest();
        test.rTName = "A";
        Console.WriteLine(test.rName);
        // >> A
        refTest test2 = test;
        test2.rName = "B";
        Console.WriteLine($"test.rName = {test.rName}, test2.rName = {test2.rName}");
        // >> test.rName = B, test2.rName = B
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}


class refTest
{
    public string rName;
}
```

Comment: `test` and `test2` are the same thing; what are you expecting to be different? (ps; I take it `test.rTName` is a typo?)

Comment: Strings in C# are quite different from strings in Java or character arrays in C. Magnetron's answer explains how strings in C# work.

Answer (score 5):

`string`, although is a reference type, it is an immutable one. That means that when you do  `name2 = "B"` you're creating a new instance and making `name2` point to the new instance, while `name` still points to the old one.

Now for your custom class, when you do `refTest test2 = test;` you're making `test2` points to the same object as `test`, and when you modify a property or field in one of them, as they both points to the same object, both `test` and `test2` will display the new value.

Comment: Now it is clear. Thanks. So everytime I declare string in the Main function it means I'm "creating" a new address (heap)? And I know that heap .

Comment: it's not the declaration that creates a new instance, it's the assignment @twinspectre .. `System.String` is a reference type. it will be `null` with 0 byte size until it is assigned to (or instantiated).

Comment: so, if I have a string named Characters (I know there's char for single characters) and I assign = "A", and I use the same variable and I assign "B" does this means A will be "stored" on its original address and B (same variable as before) will be "stored" on a different address?

Comment: I don't know if these links will persist, but here is a screenshot of heap of uninstantiated string https://pasteboard.co/JJl2RhX.png note that args is a string array. and a couple steps later it is instantiated. https://pasteboard.co/JJl6h64.png

Comment: I will say that even though I did expect to see `string name2 = name` be created on the Heap as a new instance (though in my ss it was `testString2 = testString1`) it wasn't.. at least not in the scope of Main.  Potentially in the scope of Encoder though, as the comparison on those snapshots did represent the increase in size.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what's happening in memory as your code progresses (assignments only). This isn't really about string being immutable, it's about what points to what:

[image]

It is never the case that making one variable equal to another establishes a chain

```
string x = "hello";

string y = x;
```

Both `y` and `x` point to "hello". It is not the case that "y points to x and then x points to hello, and if you change what x points to, y will see it"

```
YES:   y --> hello <-- x
NO:    y --> x --> hello
```

But you *do* have a chain when some variable points to a class, and that class has a variable that points to something else. This is what you had with your refTest; your `test` and `test2` point to an instance of reftest, which points to a name A, and you later swapped the name out.. This establishes a chain of references whereby swapping some part of the chain out means that something upstream sees it

Comment: Everytime I declare a variable it means new address is being "created" on the heap.

Comment: I'm going to say "no", but it's not entirely clear what you mean. Read up on how the stack and heap are used in C#. Avoid falling into traps of overly simplistic rules of thumb like "value types live on the stack and reference types live on the heap". Your question isn't really anything at all to do with stack and heap